# understanding the value of the crossorigin = "use credentials" attribute when it sends user credentials

Tags: html

I wanted to know if I understood correctly how crossorigin attribute works when it sends user data...

As I understand it, there is a place on the server that stores user informaion, where users will access to use a resource. Using the crossorigin attribute, user data is sent and when it's found in the server, it'll allow the user to use the resource.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's a way to provide support for CORS, it defines how an element (*resource*) handles a crossorigin request.
So it's similar to what you're saying, it's a way to get users' credentials without it needing to be known by you. There are other options, like `anonymous`. You can find all the information you need in the documentation. Here you have a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) to one documentation with some explanation examples.
So, when a user wants to access a resource that it's set with `crossorigin` `use-credentials`, then it'll be necessary for the user to identify, using cookies, SSL certificate, whatever. This will go in the request and will reach the server. If their credentials are valid, they will be allowed to access the resource, if they don't, he won't have access to it.

Comment: please confirm .... user data is sent to the server and when such a user is found in the server it is allowed to use the cross origin resource.

Comment: @SamvelGhumashyan yes, that's it. I've updated my answer to add this information.

Comment: Please, one more question :) user data is sent to the server using a cookie, that is, the username and password with which I entered to the site www.example01.com, where the link to the resource is located, or user data, that is, the username and password , with which I entered to the site www.example02 .com, where (on this server) this resource is located.

sorry for misunderstanding. I am new to programming

Comment: @SamvelGhumashyan well, you send your credentials unconsciously (PC, client, send it for you), no matter which way (cookies, JWT, certificate, etc). Then, when it reaches the server, the server will check if the credentials you're sending are correct (exists). If they do, the server will return the message, if they don't, it will return an error message, probably a 402 HTTP code.